# Are the castles of Bellinzona included in the Swiss Travel Pass?

Tags: switzerland

Is the entrance fee to all the 3 castles of Bellinzona included in the [Swiss Travel Pass](https://www.swiss-pass.ch/swiss-pass/) ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are various flavors for the Travel Pass but the answer appears to be "Yes". Some Swiss Travel Passes come with the "Schweizer Museumspass" which gives access to 500+ Museums in Switzerland.

They have a search option (https:/www.museumspass.ch/museen-finden/) and looking in Bellinzona yields

[image]

There is probably some fine print somewhere that spells out the exact terms and conditions and I recommend reading that up before booking.